# How to use NOT EXISTS and JOIN at the same time?

Tags: sql, hana, sapb1

We are required to display UID that is in BOS_BARCODE_IT_LOG but not exists in BOS_BARCODE_DO_LOG

The reason that I joined with OITM is because the user asked for the selection Criteria in SAP Business One.

```
SELECT X0."DATE",X0."ITEMCODE", X0."UID"
FROM "BOS_BARCODE_IT_LOG" X0 JOIN OITM X1 ON

X0."ITEMCODE" = X1."ItemCode"

WHERE
X1."ItemCode" =  '[%0]'

AND  NOT EXISTS (
SELECT X2."UID" FROM "BOS_BARCODE_DO_LOG" X2
WHERE X0."ITEMCODE" = X2."ITEMCODE" AND
X0."UID" = X2."UID" AND
X0."DATE" = X2."DATE"
)
```

We need that '[%0]' in order to display

[image]

The problem is that, when I tried to search any items there, the query returns no result.

What I've tried.

I Select only from one table without OITM, and neverthless, did not provide Query Selection Criteria.

I Tried this as well

```
SELECT X0."DATE",X0."ITEMCODE", X0."UID"
FROM "BOS_BARCODE_IT_LOG" X0

WHERE 

X0."ITEMCODE" = '[%0]' AND

NOT EXISTS (
SELECT X1."UID" FROM "BOS_BARCODE_DO_LOG" X1
WHERE X0."ITEMCODE" = X1."ITEMCODE" AND
X0."UID" = X1."UID" AND
X0."DATE" = X1."DATE"
)
```

And it provide error.

1). [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ")": line 14 col 1  'Received Alerts' (OAIB) (at pos 299)

Another thing, is it possible to use subquery with more than one tables and provide the expected result (Not just blank result)

What I learned in the tutorial that subquery only used for one table.
This is one of the examples.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> We are required to display `UID` that is in `BOS_BARCODE_IT_LOG` but not exists in `BOS_BARCODE_DO_LOG`.

I don't undersand how your queries actually relate to the question (they have one additional table  `oitm`, and many more columns). From the description of your question it seems like you want:

```
select bi.uid
from bos_barcode_it_log bi
where not exists (select 1 from bos_barcode_do_log bd where bd.uid = bi.uid)
```

If you need `oitm` for filtering, you can join (if there is not more than one row in per `itemcode` in `oitm`), or use `exists`:

```
select bi.uid
from bos_barcode_it_log bi
where 
    exists (select 1 from oitm o where o.itemcode = bi.itemcode)
    and not exists (select 1 from bos_barcode_do_log bd where bd.uid = bi.uid)
```

Comment: Yeah, however. I need to join another table called OITM. Is it possible? Would it help if I include the structure of table?

Comment: @MarioSaputra: I added another query to my answer.

Comment: The other code you add is actually a good code. However, it misses the requirement that I need, the input parameter settings. In SAP, we need to have '[%0]' in the query. I tried to put the '[%0]' in the inner query, and it gave an immediate no result, rather than asking the user to input certain itemcode. The input parameter I mentioned here is provided in the picture from orignal post.

Comment: Here's what I tried.

select bi.uid, bi.ItemCode, bi.date
from bos_barcode_it_log bi
where 
    exists (select 1 from oitm o where o.itemcode = bi.itemcode and o.itemcode = '[%0]')
    and not exists (select 1 from bos_barcode_do_log bd where bd.uid = bi.uid)